# Translate string in template with dynamic value

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-i18n

In my template file I have something like this:

```
{% blocktrans %}There are {{news|length}} news{% endblocktrans %}
```

But translation always misses the `{{news|length}}` in it (prints out 'There are news').

My django.po file is auto generated via `django-admin.py makemessages --all`

```
msgid "There are %(news|length)s news"
msgstr "%(news|length)s tane haber var"
```

I know that I can try to pass this string in views.py but is there any way to do it in templates or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the filter within the blocktrans tag itself.

```
{% blocktrans with news=news|length %}There are {{ news }} news{% endblocktrans %}
```